# Facebook login issue with business_management permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

**Intro**

I've included in my web app the code to allow the user to connect to their facebook account.
One of the permissions included is the 'business_management'.

**The issue**

When I include said permission the first time I login into FB everything works fine. But, from then on, even if I log out the next time I log in I never get to insert my email/pwd or to choose which pages I want to list. The only way to reset it it's by clearing the cookies.

**Conclusion**
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for a reason I do not understand so feel free to comment if you have more info.

Solution:
Set out the procedure of logout even if the user did not complete the login procedure and delete all previously granted permissions.